# ExtJs 4.1.0 Buffered grid + local sorting/filtering

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1.0
I am having a buffered grid and I would like to enable local sorting on the this grid.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Currently when i use buffered grid then sorting is coming as disabled even though i have give the sortable config to the columns for which i want sorting enables.

Can we do local sorting/filtering in buffered grid ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new plugin in ExtjS grid "bufferedrenderer" that may fit your use case better than a buffered store. Local sorting and filtering work as usual, only the grid content is rendered dynamically on scroll. We are using this to display tens of thousands of rows.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259314-Infinite-Grid-Filters-won-t-work&p=949486&viewfull=1#post949486